# How to avoid getting garbage values while inserting a new node after a given node in singly linked lists?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, singly-linked-list

I was restricted to using only one way of inserting a new node after a given node and implementing the linked list. I was getting a garbage value in my output. I'm not clear on how I can resolve this issue. Any help is appreciated thanks in advance.

> 

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

void insertAfter(struct Node  *prevNode,int newData){
    if(prevNode == NULL){
        printf("the given previous node cannot be NULL");
        return;
    }
    struct Node* newNode = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newNode->data = newData;
    newNode->next = prevNode->next;
    prevNode->next = newNode;
}
void printList(struct Node *head){
    while(head!=NULL){
        printf(" %d ", head->data);
        head = head->next;
    }
}


int main()
{

  struct Node* head = NULL;
  struct Node* second = NULL;
  struct Node* third = NULL;
  
  head = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  second = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  third = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

  head->data = 9;
  head->next = second;
  insertAfter(head->next, 8);
  third->data = 10;
  third->next = NULL;

  printf("\n Created Linked list is: ");
  printList(head);
 
  return 0;
}
```

Generated output:: 9 0 8
Expected output: 9 8 10

Comment: @ayasuryan Mutyala You need to set the data member next to NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code snippet

```
  struct Node* head = NULL;
  struct Node* second = NULL;
  struct Node* third = NULL;
  
  head = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  second = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  third = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

  head->data = 9;
  head->next = second;
  insertAfter(head->next, 8);
  third->data = 10;
  third->next = NULL;
```

is wrong. The node pointed to by the pointer `third` is not included in the list and the node pointed to by the pointer `second` has uninitialized data members.

At least you should write for example

```
  struct Node* head = NULL;
  struct Node* second = NULL;
  struct Node* third = NULL;
  
  head = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  second = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  third = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

  head->data = 9;
  head->next = second;
  second->data = 10;
  second->next = third;  
  third->data = 11;
  third->next = NULL;
  insertAfter(head->next, 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
head->next = second;
```

Here `second` contains garbage. You want

```
head->next = NULL;
```

Then `second` and `third` variables are not needed. Instead you need to call `insertAfter` twice to insert 8 and 10.